# The pro-discrete space of quasicomponents of a topological space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a topological space.
Consider the functor $P^X : \textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Set}$ that sends each set $Y$ to the set of continuous maps $X \to Y$.
It is not hard to check that $P^X : \textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Set}$ preserves finite limits and is accessible, so it is pro-representable.
Let $\hat{\pi}_0 (X)$ be the pro-set representing $P^X$.
This is the same pro-set that shape theory (at least in its topos-theoretic form) gives for the path components of the shape of $X$.
On the other hand, let $\pi_0 (X)$ be the space of quasicomponents of $X$,  i.e. the set of quasicomponents of $X$ with the quotient topology.

**Question.**
What is the relationship between $\hat{\pi}_0 (X)$ and $\pi_0 (X)$?

Somewhat more precisely, consider the functor $\left| {-} \right| : \textbf{Pro} (\textbf{Set}) \to \textbf{Top}$ that "realises" each formal inverse limit of sets as a concrete inverse limit of discrete spaces.
Its image is contained in the full subcategory of totally separated spaces.
The space of quasicomponents is also totally separated.
In fact, $\pi_0 (X)$ is the universal totally separated space that $X$ maps to.
(In other words, $\pi_0$ is the left adjoint of the inclusion of the full subcategory of totally separated spaces.)
Thus, there is a canonical continuous map $\pi_0 (X) \to \left| \hat{\pi}_0 (X) \right|$.
It is injective, but I am not sure whether it is topological embedding, nor whether it is surjective.
Is it a homeomorphism in general?
If not, is there some well known class of spaces $X$ for which it is a homeomorphism?

---

For completeness, let me give a concrete description of $\hat{\pi}_0 (X)$.

We may think of $P^X (Y)$ as the set of $Y$-indexed partitions of $X$ into (possibly empty) open subspaces.
This gives us a formula for $P^X$:
$$P^X (Y) \cong \varinjlim_{R : \mathbf{P} (X)^\textrm{op}} Y^{\# (X / R)}$$

Here, $\mathbf{P} (X)$ is the poset of equivalence relations $R$ on $X$ where the $R$-equivalence classes are open subsets of $X$, and $\# (X / R)$ is the *set* of $R$-equivalence classes.
Note that $\mathbf{P} (X)$ is a filter in the poset of all equivalence relations on $X$.
Therefore:
$$\hat{\pi}_0 (X) \cong \varprojlim_{R : \mathbf{P} (X)} \# (X / R)$$

**Proposition.**
The canonical map $\pi_0 (X) \to \left| \hat{\pi}_0 (X) \right|$ is injective.

*Proof.*
From the above description, a point $E$ of $\left| \hat{\pi}_0 (X) \right|$ is a choice of $R$-equivalence class $E_R$ for every $R$ in $\mathbf{P} (X)$, such that if $R \subseteq R'$ then $E_R \subseteq E_{R'}$.
Consider $\check{E} = \bigcap_{R : \mathbf{P} (X)} E_R$.
Given any $x \in \check{E}$, $\check{E}$ is the quasicomponent of $X$ containing $x$: indeed, given any clopen neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, if $R$ is the equivalence relation on $X$ with equivalence classes $U$ and $X \setminus U$, the fact that $x \in \check{E}$ implies $E_R = U$.
Hence, the canonical map $X \to \left| \hat{\pi}_0 (X) \right|$ identifies two points if and only if they are in the same quasicomponent. 　◼

Comment: A quasicomponent is the intersection of all clopen neighbourhoods of a point. On the other hand, an element of the inverse limit is a choice of non-empty clopen subspace in every partitioning of the space that is compatible with refinement, and taking the intersection of all the chosen clopen subspaces gives the quasicomponent of some point.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the intersection might be empty if the space is not sober… hmmm…

Comment: Even if the space is Sober that doesn't seem clear to me. A point of the limit is a special kind of filter of clopen subsets (To be precise, it is a filter on the boolean algebra of clopen set such that for every disjoint cover, one of the element is in the filter), but without compactness assumption, I don't see why each such filter would corresponds to a quasicomponent.

Comment: Right. I think I can convince myself that $\hat{\pi}_0 (\mathbb{Q})$ has "extra" points not corresponding to any quasicomponent. I wonder what the right way to think about this is, then...

Comment: I have a paper in preparation (I can share a preliminary version by mail) on this construction in the case of locales. In this case, $\hat{\pi}_0(X)$ is the universal zero-dimensional locale under $X$, but the map $X \to \hat{\pi}_0(X)$ might not be a surjection in general. Its image (in the sense of the epi-sublocale factorization) is the universal totally disconnected locale under $X$ (in the sense that it has a basis of clopen). If $X$ is a sober space, then maybe $\pi_0(X)$ corresponds to this image?

Comment: @SimonHenry That could be interesting. Please do send it to me. My current email address is on arXiv.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find your current email (or is the Cambridge one still correct?). The email on my webpage works.